# Apply function taking one argument to a value in Python

Tags: python, list, variables

I don't really get how that works, why is 10 not an variable of the function? I never saw a case where you would apply a function to an item outside of that function. I don't want the answer to the problem, just want to understand it.

Thanks guys

Write a function called general_poly, that meets the specifications below.
For example, general_poly([1, 2, 3, 4])(10) should evaluate to 1234 because 1∗103+2∗102+3∗101+4∗100

So in the example the function only takes one argument with general_poly([1, 2, 3, 4]) and it returns a function that you can apply to a value, in this case x = 10 with general_poly([1, 2, 3, 4])(10).

Answer (score 2):

It's asking you for `general_poly` to return a function, e.g.:

```
def general_poly(L):
    def inner(x):
        return sum(x+e for e in L)
    return inner

general_poly([1,2,3,4])(10)
# 11+12+13+14 = 50
```

This should give you enough to be able to work through your homework.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! All I needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
def general_poly (L):
    """ L, a list of numbers (n0, n1, n2, ... nk)
    Returns a function, which when applied to a value x, returns the value 
    n0 * x^k + n1 * x^(k-1) + ... nk * x^0 """

    def inner(x):
        L.reverse()
        return sum(e*x**L.index(e) for e in L)
    return inner
```